# deepCopy of Cocoa containers - how to prevent endless recursions?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

As Cocoa only offers shallow copying for its built-in containers, I have written my own DeepCopy class extensions for the ones, for which I sometimes need deep copies.

For example for NSArray it looks like this:

```
#import "NSArray+CopyDeep.h"

@implementation NSArray (CopyDeep)

- (NSArray*) copyDeep
{
    NSMutableArray* retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.count];
    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<self.count; i++)
    {
        id element = [self objectAtIndex:i];
        [retVal addObject:[[element  respondsToSelector:@selector(copyDeep)]?[element copyDeep]:[element copy] autorelease]];
    }
    return [[retVal autorelease] copy];
}

- (NSMutableArray*) mutableCopyDeep
{
    NSMutableArray* retVal = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.count];
    for(NSUInteger i=0; i<self.count; i++)
    {
        id element = [self objectAtIndex:i];
        [retVal addObject:[[element respondsToSelector:@selector(mutableCopyDeep)]?[element mutableCopyDeep]:[element mutableCopy] autorelease]];
    }
    return retVal;
}

@end
```

But now it has come to my attention that one could add a container-instance b to container-instance a and also add a to b.
In this case, when calling copyDeep on a,this would recurse in a call to copyDeep on b, which would call it again on a, and so on: endless recursion.

Can you give me some ideas please, how to easily handle this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the objects in these collections conform to NSCoding, then you don't need to implement your own deep copy code.  Try this:

```
NSArray *arrayIWantCopied;
...

NSArray *clone = [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayIWantCopied]];
```

When you use NSArchiving, all the issues of encoding multiple references to the same object are handled for you.

Comment: This is really the best way to do a deep copy IMO. As long as everybody is encodable, the framework will handle it for you.

Comment: And you don't mind having a 2x memory requirement (to hold the temporary archive)

Comment: - Wouldn't it be better to use NSArchiver and NSUnarchiver or NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver but not to mix NSKeyedArchiver with NSUnarchiver?
- I assume, that mutability stays the same, so the copy of mutable (sub-)object will be mutable, the one of an immutable will be immutable?
- So the whole class extension implementation class would just be:
- (id) copyDeep
{
 return [NSUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSArchiver encodeRootObject:self]];
}
?
- So I guess, I could also just add it to a base class of all supported (but of no non-supported) classes to reduce redundancy?

Comment: OK, has to be like this: return [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self]];
as NSArchiver/NSunArchiver are unavailable on iOS.

Comment: Well, actually [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self]] retain]; as the name of copyDeep begins with copy (I could of cause call it deepCopy instead, but i think, it would be strange, if you don't own a deepCopy, although you own a copy...)

Answer (score 1):

Implement the actual copying with a method along the lines of:

```
- (NSArray *)copyDeepWithAncestors:(NSDictionary *)ancestorMapping;
```

Add deep-copyable objects you encounter to `ancestorMapping` as keys, with the copies as their corresponding values. If you encounter an object that's already in there, just replace with the already-created copy rather than recursing again. (You'll probably want to create the dictionary as a [CFDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html) to get around NSDictionary's key limitations, but they're [toll-free bridged](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html), so you can still use it as an NSDictionary once it's created.)